# "Шановний" та "вельмишановний"

Tags: вибір-слова

Коли потрібно у офіційних зверненнях писати «шановний», «вельмишановний», «високопоставлений»? Чи є між ними різниця? Чи є якісь окремі випадку щодо їх вживання?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вельмишановний занадто формально, але допустимо. Високопоставлений взагалі у звертаннях не зустрічала, тим паче саме слово стилістично не дуже вдалий варіант, попахує калькою з російської. Шановний - єдиний оптимальний варіант.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші правила якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень.
А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо.
Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).
Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].